# Visual studio some code in darker colours

Tags: visual-studio

I searched but couldn't manage to find anything on this. I'm wondering why some words are in darker colours?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you are not using remote and shell.

So if you remove them from the require method it will not affect your application as long as you don't need them